# What is the name of this thing like a building on top of a roof?

Tags: image-identification, architecture

It's like a building on top of a roof. I don’t know how to describe it too well, but you can walk out of it and be on the actual building's roof. This building thing is always on a roof, and can have AC coolers on top. Sadly I’m ill so  the name is lost to me. Help?

[image]

Comment: Elevator equipment room.

Comment: Or, more broadly, *mechanical room*...

Answer (score 4):

Although the most common use of the word *penthouse* is the biggest, most luxurious apartment at the top of a tall building, in British English at least, it is also used to describe the building your photo. From [Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/penthouse):

> **penthouse** in British (ˈpɛntˌhaʊs) noun
>
> 1. a flat or maisonette built onto the top floor or roof of a block of flats
> 2. a construction on the roof of a building, esp one used to house machinery
> 3. a shed built against a building, esp one that has a sloping roof
> 4. [real tennis] the roofed corridor that runs along three sides of the court

Comment: Also: *penthouse* in American:  **3. a** an apartment or other houselike structure built on the roof of a building (*ibid.*).

Answer (score 3):

The Scottish Building regulations manual calls this a

> **rooftop plant room**.

[Scottish Building Regulations](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xM1WCMrs0hkC&pg=PA164&lpg=PA164&dq=rooftop+plant+room&source=bl&ots=NoXVprdOmN&sig=j_mv-a0Bu_2E8PAMgmJnNif8HFo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJkpnit6_YAhVrCsAKHR70BMAQ6AEIWTAK#v=onepage&q=rooftop%20plant%20room&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

The term *mechanical penthouse* (or MPH) is common in North America, especially on taller buildings.

Comment: Thanks, Lurk. Can you please give a couple of examples of this usage?

Comment: Note that, though the term 'mechanical penthouse' may be the exact way to render it, it is much much more rare than the simple 'penthouse' - which is to say it sounds weird to actually say 'mechanical penthouse'. Use 'penthouse' instead.

Answer (score 1):

If it were smaller and only intended to be a weatherproof enclosure for the top of the stairwell, you might call it a bulkhead:

Quoting [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bulkhead) (Random House dictionary):

> **bulkhead**
>
> 4. Building Trades.
>
>    b. boxlike structure, as on a roof, covering a stairwell or other opening.

I'm thinking the specific kind of structure you see there is somewhere between this word and *penthouse*, as advised in another answer, so I'm somewhat at a loss to suggest one over the other.

It might be better described by its in-context use, e.g. *utility room* or *roof access structure*.

Answer (score -3):

I'm quite sure you are referring to the attic.

An attic is defined as **a space or room inside or partly inside the roof of a building.**

Comment: I don't think the construction shown in the photo would be called an attic. An attic is under the pitched roof of a traditional building. The picture shows a modern flat-roofed building.

Comment: Note the "inside or partly inside the roof" -- this one is **on** the roof. It's a "penthouse".

Comment: This is definitely not an attic, either by definition or apparent use.  An attic is usually either a storage area or an improvised living area whose "walls" are defined more by the lines of the roof than those of the walls below the level of the attic.